# Installing Ubuntu Question

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04

I have a question about installing Ubuntu 14.04 (I think, it's the newest distro. to my knowledge). I am currently running a dual boot to test it out, and I really love it!

My question is, will I be able to transfer files from my Windows to my Ubuntu before completely installing, and will I be able to save my Windows Restore files just incase I want to go back to Windows 8?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just stay dual booted?  You can relatively effectively run a dual boot environment on your computer.

---

To answer your actual questions:

(1) Yes, you will be able to transfer files from Windows to Ubuntu before removing Windows, if you truly don't want a dual boot configuration.

(2) Your Windows restore points don't actually *save* your Windows OS entirely.  When you remove Windows, your restore points go away, so you'd have to reinstall Windows from scratch, then, if you want to go back to Windows after completely removing it.  This is why dual boot environments can be okay, so that if you don't want to completely lose what's on Windows, so you don't have to reinstall everything if you ever want to switch.

Comment: So for question 2, would it be easier to just write down my Windows 8 key, and if I ever want to change to just re install it like such?

Comment: @New2Ubuntu Yes, but this is why dual boot environments exist, so both operating systems can exist on the same system, and you can choose which to use at boot time.  In my case, I have to have such an environment, as some of my IT security courses I'm taking require Windows for the utilities, and the utilities don't work with Wine (which can run some Windows executables).  But that's kinda why dual booting can be a good alternative - so you don't have to really get rid of either, and can switch between them when you want to use one or the other.

Comment: Okay, I understand. I think I may just go with a dual-boot for now. Thanks!

Comment: @New2Ubuntu You're welcome!  Note your key might not work for Windows with the standard installer, too, so that's another reason why I'm suggesting you stick with a dual boot for now.  Unless you know for certain you will never use Windows again, dual booting is a better idea

Comment: I really wanted to use Ubuntu to speed up my games I played on Windows, and do graphic designing on there aswell, pretty much things you are able to do on Windows, but in a faster fashion. I will try a dual-boot, and if I find myself not using Win. much, or at all, i'm making the switch. Thanks again @thomasw

Comment: Ubuntu doesn't really help speed up your games... just an FYI.  Also, if this answer helped, and you don't need any answers anymore, please mark this answer as accepted.